# PDFBox Java EE Not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, pdfbox

I wrote a wrapper class to abstract some functions of PDFBox I use often. It works fine with Java SE but for some reason it does not work with Java EE.

All the appropriate jars are where they should be, including the commons-logging.

Is there a know reason why this does not work with Java EE? Is there a workaround?

Here is the error I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObject
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
at com.idt.nwu.servlet.IDTNWUServlet.service(IDTNWUServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: No, check your EAR file. Some references might be missing. Did you include all external JARs either in your EAR or WAR, and reference them correspondingly? PDFBox definitely works in JEE environments, so it must be a configuration issue or library incompatiblities...

Comment: Thanks! You set met on the correct path. I put the required jars in my Tomcat Server's lib directory. Everything works now...

Comment: np, but I'd rather place them in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Awesome, that makes more sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the required jars in WEB-INF/lib directory. Everything works now...